# Check if one character in string is numeric or is a letter [Python]

Tags: python, string, isnumeric

I want to check the string and see if at least one of the characters in the string is a letter or number. How would i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `re.search`

```
if re.search(r'[a-zA-Z\d]', string):
```

It will return a match object if the string contain at-least a letter or a digit.

**Example:**

```
>>> s = "foo0?"
>>> re.search(r'[a-zA-Z\d]', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='f'>
>>> s = "???"
>>> re.search(r'[a-zA-Z\d]', s)
>>> s = "???0"
>>> re.search(r'[a-zA-Z\d]', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 4), match='0'>
>>>
```

Comment: Never noticed that python 3 changed the `repr` of match objects, that's nice.

Comment: So would the "foo0" then return as true?

Answer (score 3):

`str.isalnum`:

```
In [16]: s = "foo"    
In [17]: s.isalnum()
Out[17]: True
In [20]: s = "123"
In [21]: s.isalnum()
Out[21]: True
In [22]: s = "foo123"
In [23]: s.isalnum()
Out[23]: True
```

Then use any:

```
any(x.isalnum() for x in  s)

In [24]: s = "!@1"   
In [25]: any(x.isalnum() for x in  s)
Out[25]: True
In [27]: s = "!@()"
In [28]: any(x.isalnum() for x in  s)
Out[28]: False
```

It will short circuit if we find any alpha or numeric character or return False if the string contains neither.

Comment: I guess the op expects "%*&^%A" to return `True` as well, since "at least one character" is a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be (don't forget to `import string`):

```
any(c in s for c in string.letters + string.digits)
```

(In contrast to the regex solution this is locale-dependent, e.g. including German umlauts etc.)